# A aplicação crasha sempre que clico no botão de calcular

Tags: java, android

É uma aplicação para calcular IMC, salvar os dados e exibi-los em uma outra interface. Porém, quando eu clico no botão para realizar o cálculo e exibir, o programa crasha. Outras classes somente servem para manter o banco SQLite.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Button botao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalcular);
        final TextView txtIdade = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtIdade);
        final int[] skIdadeNewValue = {0};
        SeekBar skIdade = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.skIdade);
        skIdade.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new
                                                   SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                                                       public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                                                                     boolean fromUser) {
                                                           skIdadeNewValue[0] = progress;
                                                       }

                                                       @Override
                                                       public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                                                       }

                                                       @Override
                                                       public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                                                           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Idade é = " +
                                                                           skIdadeNewValue[0],
                                                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                           txtIdade.setText("Idade = " + skIdadeNewValue[0]);
                                                       }
                                                   });

        botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                PessoaCtr crud = new PessoaCtr(getBaseContext());
                RadioButton edtSexo = null;
                String estudante = null;
                String idoso = null;
                String empregado = null;
                String sexo = null;
                CheckBox chkEstudante;
                CheckBox chkEmpregado;
                CheckBox chkIdoso;
                RadioButton rbMasc;
                RadioButton rbFem;
                ToggleButton tgConfirma;
                EditText result;
                chkEstudante = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkEstudante);
                chkEmpregado = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkEmpregado);
                chkIdoso = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkIdoso);
                rbMasc = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbMasc);
                rbFem = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbFem);
                tgConfirma = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tgConfirma);
                if (chkEstudante.isChecked() == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Estudante foi selecionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    estudante = chkEstudante.getText().toString();
                }
                if (chkEmpregado.isChecked() == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Empregado foi selecionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    empregado = chkEmpregado.getText().toString();
                }
                if (chkIdoso.isChecked() == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Idoso foi selecionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    idoso = chkIdoso.getText().toString();
                }
                if (rbMasc.isChecked() == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Masculino foi selecionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    edtSexo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbMasc);
                    sexo = edtSexo.getText().toString();
                }
                if (rbFem.isChecked() == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Feminino foi selecionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    edtSexo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbFem);
                    sexo = edtSexo.getText().toString();
                }
                if (tgConfirma.isChecked() == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Você curtiu o aplicativo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Você não curtiu o aplicativo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


                EditText edtNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNome);
                EditText edtPeso = (EditText) findViewById((R.id.editPeso));
                EditText edtAltura = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAltura);
                EditText edtImc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.imc);
                SeekBar skIdade = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.skIdade);

                int idadeInt = skIdadeNewValue[0];
                int resultadoImc = Integer.parseInt(edtPeso.getText().toString()) * (Integer.parseInt(edtAltura.getText().toString())* Integer.parseInt(edtAltura.getText().toString()));
                edtImc.setText(String.valueOf(resultadoImc));

                chkEmpregado = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkEmpregado);
                chkEstudante = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkEstudante);
                chkIdoso = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkIdoso);
                String nome = edtNome.getText().toString();
                String peso = edtPeso.getText().toString();
                String altura = edtAltura.getText().toString();
                String stringidade = txtIdade.getText().toString();
                String imc = edtImc.getText().toString();
                String idade = txtIdade.toString();

                String resultado = crud.insertPessoa(nome, peso, altura, sexo, idade, estudante, idoso, empregado, imc);
                edtNome.setText("");
                edtPeso.setText("");
                edtAltura.setText("");
                edtSexo.setText("");
                txtIdade.setText("");
                chkEstudante.setText("");
                chkIdoso.setText("");
                chkEmpregado.setText("");
                edtImc.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), resultado, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Ficaria grato se alguém pudesse me ajudar, estou iniciando nessa área.

Comment: Você poderia compartilha o fonte do projeto no github? Você ja debugou para analisar em qual linha o problema acontece?

Comment: Você tem que adicionar na sua pergunta o que aparece no seu logcat quando cracheia. Não tem como a gente reproduzir pois não possui código suficiente.

Comment: Acabei de colocar o projeto lá: https://github.com/nmp2605/androidIMC

Comment: Adicione o que é exibido no Logcat! fica mais fácil de ajudar!

Answer (score 0):

Foi encontrado esse erro:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""  at
>   java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)

Nessa parte:

```
int resultadoImc = Integer.parseInt(edtPeso.getText().toString()) * 
(Integer.parseInt(edtAltura.getText().toString())* 
Integer.parseInt(edtAltura.getText().toString()));
```

Poderia fazer isso:

```
 int resultadoImc = 0;
 try {
       resultadoImc = Integer.parseInt(edtPeso.getText().toString()) * 
(Integer.parseInt(edtAltura.getText().toString()) * 
Integer.parseInt(edtAltura.getText().toString()));
      }
 catch (Exception e){}
  edtImc.setText(String.valueOf(resultadoImc));
```